# post url in c# and retrieve html

Tags: c#, url, post

I' ve to get the html code of a particular page. The url format is:

http://www.externalwebsite.com/dir/page.html?p1=parameter1value&p2=parametervalue2

When I get the html code of this page there's a list of hidden values filled with the p1 and p2 paramter wrote before in the querystring. Then there's a POST action which redirects to "/dir/page.html": In this page there's the html content I need.

Is there any way to get the html content of "dir/page.html" ?

Any help is really appreciated!

Thank you

I already implemented the GetResponseStream by using the streamreader, but I get this piece of HTML:

```
<form name="myForm" method="post" action="/dir/page.html" accept-charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <input type="hidden" name="p1" value="parameter1">
    <input type="hidden" name="p2" value="parameter2">
</form>
```

Comment: what exactly are you wanting to achieve? Are the hidden fields populated by client code?

Comment: I don't know how the hiddenfields are populated because "externalwebsite" it's not a website managed by me.
In any case I try to explain again how the things are going:
-the user goes on http://www.externalwebsite.com/dir/page.html?p1=parameter1value&p2=parametervalue2
-there's a POST action on http://www.externalwebsite.com/dir/page.html with the html code I need to get.

I suppose there's a session/cookie or something else which "says" to the website "ok the page has been correctly called, show html content!".

Comment: You may be best off creating an instance of InternetExplorer in your app and navigating to the page - this will simulate the user experience, you may then be able to retrieve the values you want.

Answer (score 1):

You want `GetResponse`. Something like..

```
HttpWebRequest request =          
    WebRequest.Create("http://www.externalwebsite.com/dir/page.html");
HttpWebResponse response  = request.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader  = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string sHTML = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: I already implemented this piece of code. See the details I've just added in my post. Thank you  :)

Answer (score 1):

You have issued a HTTP GET Request but when submitting a form you have to issue a HTTP PUT request to the server which contains the two parameters p1 and p2.

You can use the `WebRequestClass` or the `WebClient` class and the `UploadValues` Method to send the parameters with a HTTP POST:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
byte[] result = wc.UploadValues("http://www.externalwebsite.com/dir/page.html", 
                                "POST", 
                                new NameValueCollection
                                    {
                                        { "p1", parameter1 }, 
                                        { "p2", parameter2 }
                                    });
```

Comment: Nothing to do...I ever get the same page with the hiddenfield html (refer to the html code I wrote in my first post).

Comment: I would suggest to start fiddler to see what the page exactly posts when submitting the form. Maybe there are more fields in the form.